# Insert X times based on column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has the following properties.

```
|  UPC  |  Cost  | Items |
--------------------------
|  abc  |  2.50  |  30   |
|  123  |  2.11  |  40   |
```

Let's say I need to copy the information into another table, but I need to do each one as its own line item... for example, I need to end with...

```
|  UPC  |  Cost  | Sold | ID |
------------------------------
|  abc  |  2.50  | NULL |  1 |
|  abc  |  2.50  | NULL |  2 |
...
|  abc  |  2.50  | NULL | 29 |
|  abc  |  2.50  | NULL | 30 |    
|  123  |  2.11  | NULL | 31 |
|  123  |  2.11  | NULL | 32 |
...
|  123  |  2.11  | NULL | 69 |
|  123  |  2.11  | NULL | 70 |
```

Is there a way to insert based off # of items in the original table?

I was thinking I could do something like this...

```
WHILE (SELECT Total FROM dbo.tempInventory) > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Inventory (UPC, Cost, Sold)
    SELECT (UPC, Cost, NULL) 
    FROM dbo.tempInventory
    UPDATE dbo.tempInventory
    SET Total = Total-1
END
```

And this would work for 1 UPC at a time. The issue is I'm working with over 3500 UPC's, and each have between 1 and 60 items to input.

Comment: Easily done with an intermediate script such as python, php etc.

Comment: I'd prefer to do it in SQL alone... the way out databases are setup it would be a pain to access it from where I'm at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it directly in SQL, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure HOW it works. Would anyone be able to explain?

```
  WITH tally AS (
      SELECT 1 n
      UNION ALL
      SELECT n + 1 FROM tally WHERE n < 100
  )
  SELECT UPC, n.n Position
  FROM dbo.tempInventory t JOIN tally n
  ON n.n <= t.Items
  ORDER BY Description, Position
```